# Multiple Jquery simple sliders on one page

Tags: jquery, function, slider

I created my first Jquery content slider (dots + slides). It works fine, but I cant implement two sliders in one page. 
How to call function on two ids? 
I just started learning JS, so I just need both sliders to work, not to make them better etc. 
Thanks

```
<div class="slider"  id="slider">
    <div class="slides">
                 <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slider"  id="slider2">
    <div class="slides">
                    <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.slajder = function() {
        return this.each(function() {

    slider = $(this);
    slider.prepend('<nav class=\"dots"><span></span><span></span></nav>');

    slides = slider.children(".slides");
    dots = slider.children(".dots");
    dot = dots.children("span");
    dot1 = dots.children("span:first-child");
    dot2 = dots.children("span:nth-child(2)");

    dot1.click(function(){
        slides.animate({
            top: '10px',
        }, 600, function() {
        // Animation complete.

        });
        dot.css("-webkit-box-shadow","#444 0 1px 1px 0px");
        $(this).css("-webkit-box-shadow","#444 0 -1px 1px 0px");
    });
    dot2.click(function(){
        slides.animate({
            top: '-130px',
        }, 600, function() {
        // Animation complete.

        });
        dot.css("-webkit-box-shadow","#444 0 1px 1px 0px");
        $(this).css("-webkit-box-shadow","#444 0 -1px 1px 0px");
    });


        });
    };
}(jQuery));

// this one goes at bottom of a page in script tags
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#slider').slajder();
});
```

And fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/lima_fil/CK2jS/

Comment: The common selector is the class "slider" so `$('.slider').slajder();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first. To apply this code to both named slider divs, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').slajder();
    $('#slider2').slajder();
});
```

Thus, you're putting the slider functionality onto each of the two blocks, separately.

(gillyspy's one-line way of doing this is better; I did them separately only because it makes the concept more obvious)

Try that first in your fiddle. It won't quite work, but it will fail in an interesting way, so go ahead and look at it.

The buttons were all affecting the second block. To understand why, you need to know about the scoping of variables in Javascript. (There are lots of explanations out there; one is http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/). The simple explanation here, however, is that variables that are implicitly declared have global scope. That means that when you applied the slajder function to the second block, the implicitly declared variables inside it were global and overwrote the (global) ones declared for the first block.

The solution is to declare them with 'var', so they'll be local:

```
var slides = slider.children(".slides");
var dots = slider.children(".dots");
var dot = dots.children("span");
var dot1 = dots.children("span:first-child");
var dot2 = dots.children("span:nth-child(2)");
```

dot3 and dot4 in the fiddle, as you seem to have already realized, are extraneous...you don't need them.