# Javascript/JQuery multiple sliders one page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Novice here, Trying to put multiple sliders on one page. Have referenced other stack overflow posts. Getting hung up trying to display slider values.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>  
<div id="http" class="ui-widget-content">
<p style="text-align:center">slider1</p>
<input id="users1"/>
<div id="slider1"></div>
</div>

<div>  
<div id="http" class="ui-widget-content">
<p style="text-align:center">slider2</p>
<input id="users2"/>
<div id="slider2"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript I was came up with:

```
$('#slider').slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 50,
  value: 1,
  step: 1,
slide: function (event, ui) {
        $( "#users").val(ui.value);
    }
 });

$("#users").change(function () {
    var numusers = slider.children("#users")
    $("#slider").slider("numusers", parseInt(this.value));
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slider1').slider();
    $('#slider2').slider();
    $('#users1').users();
    $('#users2').users();
});
```

From what I saw here:
[Multiple Jquery simple sliders on one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311208/multiple-jquery-simple-sliders-on-one-page) I was suffering from a global variable problem when not calling the functions at the end. Basically both sliders would move the value for users id in first div.

Below is what I started with for reference:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 50,
  value: 1,
  step: 1,
slide: function (event, ui) {
        $( "#users").val(ui.value);
    }
 });

$("users").change(function () {
    $("#slider").slider("users", parseInt(this.value));
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest problem is the selectors. Each element must have unique Id.
For example, jquery will never know who is "#users" because don't have any tag with this id, so you should change to users1 or users2

```
slide: function (event, ui) {
    $( "#users2").val(ui.value);
}
```

I prepare a JSFiddle with an example that works 
https://jsfiddle.net/kevynsax/jnwhoztp/1/

```js
const getUpdaterSlide = (slider, input) => () => {
 const numUsers = $("#"+input).val();
  console.log(slider);
  $("#"+slider).slider("option", "value", numUsers);
}

const getUpdaterInput = input => (event, ui) => $("#"+input).val(ui.value);

const options = {
  min: 0,
  max: 50,
  value: 1,
  step: 1,
}

const getOptions = input => ({...options, slide: getUpdaterInput(input)});

$(document).ready(function () {
 [
   {slider: "slider1", input: "users1"}, 
    {slider: "slider2", input: "users2"}
  ].forEach(({slider, input}) => {
   $('#'+slider).slider(getOptions(input));
    $('#'+input).change(getUpdaterSlide(slider, input));
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.ui-widget-content{
  margin: 24px 16px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div>  
  <div id="http" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p style="text-align:center">slider1</p>
    <input id="users1" value="0"/>
    <div id="slider1"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="http2" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p style="text-align:center">slider2</p>
    <input id="users2" value="0"/>
    <div id="slider2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```